# fedena windows installation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fedena

Fedena installation issue. Unable to create db via `rake db:create`. All gems seem to be of correct versions for the fedena app. `Config/database.yml` apparently correct. One possible reason for inability to create db in MySQL are the differences in RoR versions specified for fedena. i.e. `ver 1.8.7` vs  `ruby 2.5.0p0` (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x64-mingw32] (latter installed on system)

Please see below:

```
d:\fedena>rake db:create
Traceback (most recent call last):
        13: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
        12: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/rake:23:in `load'
        11: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:26:in `<top (required)>'
        10: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         9: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         8: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
         7: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         6: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         5: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/win32.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
         4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/win32.rb:3:in `<module:Rake>'
         3: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         2: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32:in `<module:AltSystem>': uninitialized constant Rake::AltSystem::Config (NameError)
Did you mean?  RbConfig
```

Any advice and guidance would be awesome.

Comment: You are using latest version of ruby. Use 1.8.7. Follow the steps mentioned here: http://projectfedena.org/install

Comment: Hi Navin, Thank you for the advice. I suspected it was that but thought that some function would have been built into newer versions of RoR to allow for apps that run on older RoR versions. I have one more issue that no amount of research is able to solve....ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [i386-mingw32]
ruby.exe: illegal switch in RUBYOPT: -E (RuntimeError)

Comment: In newer rails version some old syntaxes are deprecated. You can not run an rails 2.3.5 , ruby 1.8.7 app in newer versions.